# Crypto exchanges comparison spreadsheet

Tags: exchanges

Is there any website or online community maintaining a spreadsheet comparing the different crypto exchanges?

Comment: What sort of comparison? And why specifically a spreadsheet?

Comment: Ideally, focus on exchange rates first. Spreadsheet for simplicity & quick overview.

Comment: good question. but I guess there is not yet enough exchanges to be compared

Comment: @Nulik you must be kidding

Comment: @AdrienBe there are about 10 exchnages to compare, and it can be done quickly

Comment: Eeeer ok i'm missing something then. Coz I keep bumping into articles comparing exchanges I never heard of.

Comment: @Nulik There are at least 68 exchanges with Ethereum as either the counter or base currency (not counting all the currency pairs of each): https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/#markets

Comment: @AdrienBe it is a marketing article. You can't name it an 'exchange' if it has a few coins in the list. An exchange has to have above 100 coins or something like that. There are more than 1000 coins right now. An exchange with 20 coins is a joke.

Comment: @AdrienBe What, specifically, about exchange rates? Average spreads? Average prices? Something else?

Comment: @lungj thanks for that link on CoinMarketCap. Pretty epic. Average spreads, average prices and other facts would be great. It'd be great to also gather info (even though subjective) such as "user-friendliness rating". Some exchanges are really for beginners (or non tech-savvy) while some others are more for advanced crypto users. Oh, and I started to scrap a couple of websites & created a spreadsheet (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Since no-one was able to provide a link, I started doing the work myself.

Feel free to comment in the spreadsheet (or here) so I can any missing exchange.

Note: I will add info on rates & so on later on.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m4cU6jiD2PsICWg02qdUmWe1OuuZBrRnxMPWin872ZU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Fairly dumb, probably not very Pythonic, and probably ignores the requirements you actually have, but the following will screen-scrape the table in the link that @lungj pointed to, and write it to a CSV file (so you can play around with a spreadsheet).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

page = urllib.urlopen("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/#markets")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(map(str, "# Source Pair Volume Price Volume Updated".split()))

    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        rows = [0] * len(tds)
        for i in xrange(len(tds)):
            rows[i] = tds[i].get_text()
        wr.writerow(rows)
```

There's actually more data in the page source that could be pulled out, but no spread information, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

- https://cryptoradar.co/
- https://www.cryptocompare.com/exchanges/#/overview
- http://www.coinparator.com/compare-exchanges/

Not spreadsheets, but it's better than nothing.